# Why doesn't R unique() work with fitted values extracted from lm() objects?

Tags: r, unique, anova

Unique finds unique values of a vector.

If I have a data frame:

```
test_data <- data.frame(x = c(rep(1.00050239485720394857,4),
                              1.00050239485720394854,rep(2.0002230948570293845,5),rep(3.0005903847502398475,5)),
                        y = c(rep(4.00423409872345,5),rep(2.034532039485722,5),rep(1.1234152304957,5)))
sapply(test_data,unique)
```

R returns:

```
            x        y
[1,] 1.000502 4.004234
[2,] 2.000223 2.034532
[3,] 3.000590 1.123415
```

As expected.

But say I fit an lm() or aov() object and then try to find unique fitted values():

```
set.seed(123)

y = rf(100,50,3,3)
x1 <- factor(c(rep("blue",25),
               rep("green",25),
               rep("orange",25),
               rep("purple",25)))

bsFit <- aov(y ~ x1)
unique(bsFit$fitted.values)
```

R returns:

```
 [1] 2.709076 2.709076 2.709076 2.709076 2.709076 2.709076
 [7] 2.709076 4.060080 4.060080 4.060080 4.060080 3.314801
[13] 3.314801 3.314801 3.314801 1.960280 1.960280 1.960280
[19] 1.960280 1.960280
```

There are clearly duplicates here.

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact in R, or most other languages.  My guess is that the "duplicate" value `2.709076` which seems to appear 7 times is actually not the same value under the hood.

Comment: R is only showing you 6 digits to the right of the full stop.

Comment: I believe I've updated my question to reflect your comments @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: @JeromeDineen  misplaced parenthesis in the round perhaps?

Comment: `unique(round(bsFit$fitted.values,6))` does the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said (@Tim-Biegeleisen especially), RStudio is formatting the output to a specific number of decimal places (remember anything printed to the console is formatted by RStudio). So the "duplicates", if correctly formatted to show all decimal places, aren't duplicates.

We can use `format` to show all decimal places:

```
format(unique(bsFit$fitted.values), digit = 22)
 [1] "2.7090760788376542" "2.7090760788376773" "2.7090760788376604" "2.7090760788376622" "2.7090760788376627"
 [6] "2.7090760788376649" "2.7090760788376640" "4.0600797479202155" "4.0600797479202164" "4.0600797479202200"
[11] "4.0600797479202146" "3.3148005388803132" "3.3148005388803128" "3.3148005388803146" "3.3148005388803137"
[16] "1.9602804435309986" "1.9602804435309984" "1.9602804435309982" "1.9602804435309988" "1.9602804435310004
```

I experimented to with the number of digits before an error was thrown and got 22.

Comment: @jerome maybe I'm misunderstanding you but that doesn't seem to contradict a floating point issue at all